# How to get the content of the tag that references idref in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I'm trying to get the name of the selecao that are playing, like in the `<jogo numero="1">` I want to get the name of the PAIS from the IDREF s1, that it is Franca.

The consult in the xpath: //id(@pais) and returns Franca and Senegal, OK, these two are the only one that have IDREF pais.
But I put this expression in the xsl and doesn't work.

Someone knows where is the error?

Here are my codes:

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file:///C:/Users/Cesar%20Frantz/Desktop/XML/trabalhoxml.xsl"?>
<Bolaocopa xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/Users/Cesar%20Frantz/Desktop/exemplo.xsd">
    <grupos>
        <grupo tipo="A">
            <pais id="s1">Franca</pais>
            <pais id="s2">Senegal</pais>
            <pais id="s3">Uruguai</pais>
            <pais id="s4">Dinamarca</pais>
        </grupo>
    </grupos>
    <jogos>
        <faseGrupos>
            <jogoGrupo id="a">
                <jogo numero="1">
                    <selecao pais="s1">0</selecao>
                    <selecao pais="s2">1</selecao>
                </jogo>
            </jogoGrupo>
        </faseGrupos>
    </jogos>
</Bolaocopa>
```

XSL:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">



<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>

<xsl:value-of select="//id(@pais)"/>

  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

SCHEMA:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2013 sp1 (x64) (http://www.altova.com) by Cesar (UNIFRA - Franciscan University Center) -->
<!--W3C Schema generated by XMLSpy v2013 sp1 (x64) (http://www.altova.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="ST_selecao">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:enumeration value="0"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="ST_pais">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Dinamarca"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Franca"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Senegal"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Uruguai"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="AT_6">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="s1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="s2"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="s3"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="s4"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="AT_5">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="A"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="AT_3">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="s1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="s2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="AT_2">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="AT_1">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="a"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_selecao">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="ST_selecao">
                <xs:attribute ref="pais"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_pais">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="ST_pais">
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_jogos">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="faseGrupos"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_jogoGrupo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="jogo"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="AT_1" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_jogo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="selecao" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="numero" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_grupos">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="grupo"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_grupo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="pais" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="tipo" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_faseGrupos">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="jogoGrupo"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="T_Bolaocopa">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="grupos"/>
            <xs:element ref="jogos"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="tipo" type="AT_5"/>
    <xs:attribute name="pais" type="xs:IDREF"/>
    <xs:attribute name="numero" type="AT_2"/>
    <xs:element name="selecao" type="T_selecao"/>
    <xs:element name="pais" type="T_pais"/>
    <xs:element name="jogos" type="T_jogos"/>
    <xs:element name="jogoGrupo" type="T_jogoGrupo"/>
    <xs:element name="jogo" type="T_jogo"/>
    <xs:element name="grupos" type="T_grupos"/>
    <xs:element name="grupo" type="T_grupo"/>
    <xs:element name="faseGrupos" type="T_faseGrupos"/>
    <xs:element name="Bolaocopa" type="T_Bolaocopa"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** : After reading your question again, I guess you want to retrieve the text value of `pais` nodes that are referenced by `selecao` nodes.
For this purpose, I would proceed as follows :

```
<xsl:template match="selecao">
    <xsl:variable name="pais" select="@pais" />
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="/Bolaocopa/grupos/grupo/pais[@id = $pais]" />
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I want to get for example Franca and Senegal from theirs idref (s1,s2):

//jogo[1]/selecao/id(@pais) with this I can get the two countries, but doesn't work when I put this expression in the xsl, the browser doesn't recognize

Comment: Yes, you understood my question, but it doesn't work as well, the answer of this should be just the two countries that have id ref pais and I get nothing

Comment: I made a mistake on the name of the attribute of the node `selecao` which is `pais` and not `id`. I edit.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is what you want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="pais" match="pais" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//selecao"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="selecao">
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="key('pais', @pais)"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces the output:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Franca</p>
    <p>Senegal</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

As the [XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#unique-id) states,

> > If a document does not have a DTD, then no element in the document will have a unique ID.

So you would have to have a DTD to use the `id()` function. I think making a DTD would be overkill here, so the above XPath expression should be plenty.

Comment: I did not know about the xsl `key` function but this is what you should use for your needs.

Comment: YES!! this is what I wanted, the function id() just work with a DTD? I'm using schema =/

Comment: Yes, it seems it only works with a DTD, but I think having to make a schema or DTD available in order for an XSLT to work right is an unnecessary hassle when the above approach is quite easy.

Comment: `ID` is a type so the document must be validated so that the type information can be applied to values. AFAIK a DTD is not required if the parser can validate the document using a referred schema. There are many ways to refer to document on a local filesystem and I have seen many apps support only one method. Some require different amount of `/` characters after `file:` and some support only relative paths (=no `file:`).